# Possible to inherit from variadic specified classes?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, template-mixins

Is it possible to do something like:

```
template<class T...>
class multi : public t1, public t2, ... {
...
};
```

Where t1 is the first template argument, t2 the second, and so forth.

Thanks in advance, and I will clean up the formatting when I get access to a real computer.

Comment: Why don't you try it?